# Wordpress Override a function from a parent theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, visual-composer

I've installed a theme on my word press that uses Visual Composer. But after installing it I found out that the theme has disabled some element from Visual Composer. After quit some time i found the file that is being executed to remove these elements.

I created a child theme in order to override this function but with no luck.

the original function goes like this:

```
if ( ! function_exists('remove-elements-from-vc') ) {

function remove-elements-from-vc() {

    /*** Remove Grid Elements if grid elements disabled */
    vc_remove_element('vc_basic_grid');
    vc_remove_element('vc_media_grid');
    vc_remove_element('vc_masonry_grid');
    vc_remove_element('vc_masonry_media_grid');
    vc_remove_element('vc_icon');
    vc_remove_element('vc_button2');
    vc_remove_element("vc_custom_heading");

    /*** Remove unused parameters from grid elements */
    if (function_exists('vc_remove_param')) {
        vc_remove_param('vc_basic_grid', 'button_style');
        vc_remove_param('vc_basic_grid', 'button_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_basic_grid', 'button_size');
        vc_remove_param('vc_basic_grid', 'filter_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_basic_grid', 'filter_style');
        vc_remove_param('vc_media_grid', 'button_style');
        vc_remove_param('vc_media_grid', 'button_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_media_grid', 'button_size');
        vc_remove_param('vc_media_grid', 'filter_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_media_grid', 'filter_style');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_grid', 'button_style');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_grid', 'button_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_grid', 'button_size');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_grid', 'filter_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_grid', 'filter_style');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_media_grid', 'button_style');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_media_grid', 'button_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_media_grid', 'button_size');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_media_grid', 'filter_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_media_grid', 'filter_style');
        vc_remove_param('vc_basic_grid', 'paging_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_basic_grid', 'arrows_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_media_grid', 'paging_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_media_grid', 'arrows_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_grid', 'paging_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_grid', 'arrows_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_media_grid', 'paging_color');
        vc_remove_param('vc_masonry_media_grid', 'arrows_color');
    }
}

add_action('vc_after_init', 'remove-elements-from-vc');
}
```

And this is what I'm trying to do in my child theme in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'vc_after_init', 'undo-remove-elements-from-vc' );
function undo-remove-elements-from-vc(){
    remove_action( 'vc_after_init', 'remove-elements-from-vc'); 
}
```

the function that is causing this action is in a file called "visual-composer-config.php" and it's being loaded from a sibling file called "load.php"

```
if (visual_composer_installed()) {
include_once ELATED_FRAMEWORK_MODULES_ROOT_DIR.'/visualcomposer/visual-composer-functions.php';
include_once ELATED_FRAMEWORK_MODULES_ROOT_DIR.'/visualcomposer/visual-composer-config.php';
}
```

I don't want to edit the original theme codes in case of any theme update later on, the changes will be removed. So i need to find a solution from the Child Theme.

Thanks

Comment: the function name in your `remove_action` call is your own function name, not the one from the parent theme... it should be `remove-elements-from-vc`

Comment: Wait... do dashes in function names even work?

Comment: My bad, i wrote the wrong function name here, in the original files i called the correct function.

Comment: the naming are just random naming, i replaced my original function names with "undo-remove-elements-from-vc" and etc ... The original functions doesn't contain "-"

Comment: Try changing the priority of your `add_action` call to earlier (the default is 10), so it looks like this: `add_action('vc_after_init', 'function_name', 5);` - 5 should be fine, it just needs to be before 10..

Comment: No luck. The function is still being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function in question is wrapped in `if ( ! function_exists('') )` (read: "if this function does not exist") you should be able to declare it before the parent does. This will prevent the code inside the parent function from ever being run.

*Note: I replaced your hyphens (`-`) because I haven't seen the hyphen syntax and went along assuming that is a typo. In my experience the proper syntax to use is underscores (`_`).*

You would add something like this to your child theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function remove_elements_from_vc() {
    return;
}
```

However, your `remove_action()` should work as well. It's possible you're function is hooking in before the parent theme's function is hooked. You can't remove an action until **after** it is added. From [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action):

> 1. You may need to prioritize the removal of the action to a hook that occurs after the action is added.
> 2. You cannot successfully remove the action before it has been added.
> 3. You also cannot remove an action after it has been run.
> 4. To remove an action the priority must match the priority with with the function was originally added.

If that is the case you could try to add it with a lesser priority:

```
add_action( 'vc_after_init', 'undo_remove_elements_from_vc', 20 );

function undo_remove_elements_from_vc(){
remove_action( 'vc_after_init', 'remove_elements_from_vc'); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DaveLak, I created the function in my child theme and gave it a priority 5, and it worked.

Comment: Great, you shouldn't need to add that empty function to an action at all though. All you are doing is declaring it before the parent. When `functions.php` is run that function is loaded into memory and "exists" to php. Because php is aware the function now "exists" the `if()` check in the parent fails and that function may as well just be a comment block. **TL;DR**: just add the function and you should be set.

Comment: @Joey- +1 - and Two comments: 1. The `-` would be illegal / not run, so you're right - that had to be a typo, and 2. When attempting to be sure that a hook hooks as early as possible, it can be run (and works) with a large negative number (such as `-9999`).  That could be useful as an alternative method to "hijack" the parent theme's hook (in case the remove action was not working for some reason).